text-overflow: ellipsis for a div with HTML tags
I have a case in a div that will contain some HTML tags, it will have paragraphs and lists. For examples:
<div class="article-block">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Some text #1</li>
        <li>Some text #2</li>
        <li>Some text #3</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
</div>

I want the content in the div will apply  text-overflow: ellipsis if it overflows the div's size. So what I have tried:
.article-block {
    width: 92mm;
    height: 85mm;
    margin-top: 2mm;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

The result will look like this:

I expected that it would look like this, there will be the "..." at the end:

Can I have some hints on how to achieve this? Thanks!
FYI: Only CSS or HTML, no JS.

You need to use line-clamp. See https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-clamp/ do not use height, the height will be set from a number of lines you declare.

Cool trick, but not what I am looking for. The ... should only appear if the content of all HTML tags inside the div overflows the div's height. If you look again at my expectation image: https://i.sstatic.net/ud0A6.png . You can see that the first paragraph still be fully displayed, and so on for other HTML tags, until they overflow the div's height. That's where the ... shows up.

?? https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zYXLjBZ what browser do you use that do not reproduce the behavior of the image you shared ? Your image is on the left side.

I use Edge. Anyway, your solution is promising, thanks for that! The only thing that I need is for the height of the div box should remain fixed, rather than shrinking based on the line-clamp.

The text-overflow property needs to be attached to the text elements like P, h1-h6 themselves and not a div that's a container element. also needs to have the white-space:nowrap property set alongside the overflow and text-overflow. Has to be block elements too, so you add display: block in the case of span elements.


.article-block {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 400px;
}
<div>
  <p class="article-block">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Some text #1</li>
    <li>Some text #2</li>
    <li>Some text #3</li>
  </ul>
  <p class="article-block">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
</div>




Thanks for your answer, but still do not what I am looking for. The "..." should only appear if all the HTML tags are overflowing. Please take a look again at my expectation image: https://i.sstatic.net/ud0A6.png

You can see that the first paragraph still be fully displayed, and so on for other HTML tags, until they overflow the div's height. That's where the ... shows up.

after a long thinking i decided to solve this problem using JavaScript and i didn't see any other solution without JS.
the approach is :
using the coordinates of the parent & child ,code will verify if the last element is inside the parent,if isn't , -webkit-line-clamp will decreased so its height will descread also until the last element became inside the parent.
and about css i think MDN explanation is enough :

The -webkit-line-clamp CSS property allows limiting of the contents of a block to the specified number of lines.
It only works in combination with the display property set to -webkit-box or -webkit-inline-box and the -webkit-box-orient property set to vertical.
In most cases you will also want to set overflow to hidden, otherwise the contents won't be clipped but an ellipsis will still be shown after the specified number of lines.




    var parent = document.querySelector(".article-block");
    var lastchild = document.querySelector(".article-block > *:last-child");
    var elementplace,parentplace;
    var i = 8;
    while(i > 1){
        elementplace = window.scrollY + lastchild.getBoundingClientRect().top + lastchild.clientHeight;
        parentplace = window.scrollY + parent.getBoundingClientRect().top + parent.clientHeight;            
        if(elementplace > parentplace){
            lastchild.style.webkitLineClamp = i.toString();
            i--;
            continue;
        }
        break;   
    }
.article-block {
  padding:5px;
    width: 80mm;
    height: 90mm;
    margin-top: 2mm;
    border:1px solid red;
}
p:last-child {
    overflow:hidden;
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
}
<div class="article-block">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Some text #1</li>
        <li>Some text #2</li>
        <li>Some text #3</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
</div>



Thanks for your answer, but still do not what I am looking for. The "..." should only appear if all the HTML tags are overflowing. Please take a look again at my expectation image: https://i.sstatic.net/ud0A6.png

@nphuly i edit the code and i changed the approach, i hope you get it.
